# How can use js.erb and json.erb templates in webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The serviceworker-rails gem has a nice example of why I want to do this. tldr I can generate the manifest using asset helpers and loops.

```
// app/javascripts/packs/manifest.json.erb

<% icon_sizes = Rails.configuration.serviceworker.icon_sizes %>
{
  "name": "My Progressive Rails App",
  "short_name": "Progressive",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
  <% icon_sizes.map { |s| "#{s}x#{s}" }.each.with_index do |dim, i| %>
    {
      "src": "<%= image_path "serviceworker-rails/heart-#{dim}.png" %>",
      "sizes": "<%= dim %>",
      "type": "image/png"
    }<%= i == (icon_sizes.length - 1) ? '' : ',' %>
  <% end %>
  ],
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

I also want to inject other rubyland configs into my packfiles such as public keys and other runtime app settings that the js bundle should have. Default rails handles this case really well with erb. How can I do basically the same thing using webpack instead of sprockets?

I tried putting a json.erb in app/javascripts/packs but no go.

Answer (score 0):

To have erb support, try `rails webpacker:install:erb`

Comment: This is true for `js.erb` files, but for `json.erb` files is harder to pull off as you need to install an additional plugin in webpack, and tweak configurations. Most of the time it is more convenient to create a controller and render the json/js in a dedicated controller, and it helps too if the json/js is dynamic in nature since it doesn't get cached when not using the webpack pipeline. It also feels more Railsy, since it is closer to the 'convention over configuration' mantra.

Comment: I agree with you^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and eventually rendered it using a dedicated controller for the manifest, which also had the advantage of not having to tweak the fingerprinted name and cache headers as the middleware in `serviceworker-rails` does.